# TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__' while parsing XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have the below input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<host xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.1">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <secret value="c2xhdmVfdXNlcl9wYXNzd29yZA=="/>
                </server-identities>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
     </management>
</host>
```

I am  iterating over all elements and when server-identities element is found , i am trying to add a new sub-element secret , with an associated attribute as below:

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

```
def parse_xml():
    tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for elements in tree.iter():
        if "server-identities" in elements.tag:
            c = ET.Element['secret']
            c.attrib['value'] = "some_value"
            elements.append(c)

if __name__=="__main__":
    parse_xml()
```

However , the line

> c = ET.Element['secret']

is causing TypeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parseXml.py", line 16, in <module>
    parse_xml()
  File "parseXml.py", line 10, in parse_xml
    c = ET.Element['secret']
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

- Is this the correct way to add an element in XML ?
- Why is the error caused?

**Edit:** Found the solution based on Keith's answer below; Below is how one can achieve it:

Firstly , the input XML has a global namespace,

```
xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.1"
```

So make sure you register this namespace before parsing the XML, or else Python will add a prefix to it, which changes the structure of the XML

```
ET.register_namespace('','urn:jboss:domain:4.1')
```

Rest of the code is as below:

```
for elements in tree.iter():
    if "server-identities" in elements.tag:
        c = ET.Element('secret')
        c.attrib['value'] = "some_value"
        elements.append(c)
        tree.write('sample.xml')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square bracket syntax means to invoke the item accessor. You want to "instantiate" the Element class, which in Python is the same syntax as a function call. Use parenthesis.

```
c = ET.Element("secret")
```

Comment: Keith , It worked. But will elements.append(c) write back to the XML ?

Comment: You have to write it out again.